# Out of Order initialization of members

Tags: c++, multithreading, initialization

I have some complex member of a class that wants initialization, yet conceptually that part of the object needs data / resources that should be fetched by a thread in the background. The object is coded to not be used before all data is at its place. Is there a tried and true way to code this kind of behaviour or should the object not be created before all data is present in the first place?

```
class A {

    A(ThreadPool pool, std::string location) {
        pool.queue_task([this, location](){
            B b = loadB(location); //e.g. load from disk
            this->setB(b);
        }
    }

    void setB(B b) { this->b = b; }

    private:

    B b;

};

class B {
    //Copy/Move semantics?
};
```

Comment: My advice, create the object once you can set its value.  uninitialized variables are just asking for trouble.  My only real exception is when getting input like `int foo; cin >> fool;`.  It's okay that `foo` wasn't initialized, the very next line takes care of it.

Comment: Thing is I basically need to fetch a list of required resources from a complex object, fetch the resources, then initialize the object before the object itself is actually created (think of a GUI needing to tell the loader what images to load to display it, yet if you do not create the whole GUI you do not yet know what to load)